# Array of struct initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

```
typedef struct { double x, y; } vec;
typedef struct { int n; vec* v; } polygon_t, *polygon;

#define BIN_V(op, xx, yy) vec v##op(vec a, vec b) { \
    vec c; c.x = xx; c.y = yy; return c; }

#define BIN_S(op, r) double v##op(vec a, vec b) { return r; }

BIN_V(sub, a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
BIN_V(add, a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
BIN_S(dot, a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y);
BIN_S(cross, a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x);

vec testPoints[] = {
                    {1, 1},
                    {3, 3},
                    {3, 5},
                    {5, 2},
                    {6, 3},
                    {7, 4}
                   };
```

What does the array of structs at last work?  I don't quite understand how `{1, 1}` become a vec.

If I want to have a `vector<vec> allPoints`, how can I push a vec into this vector?  This doesn't work `allPoints.push_back({1, 2});`, as well as `allPoints.push_back(new vec(1, 2));`

Comment: c++, i think it is the same, the only thing is c doesn't have vector.

Comment: No, C and C++ are not the same. Note that you don't need `typedef struct` in C++.

Comment: i mean, this code was originally from C, I changed to C++ just because I want to use Vector.  It can compile in C++ without the vector push

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{}` is an initializer and:

```
vec v = { 2, 3 };
```

is equivalent to:

```
vec v;
v.x = 2;
v.y = 4;
```

For an array:

```
int myints[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

would initialise the elements in the array:

```
myints[0] = 1;
myints[1] = 2;
myints[2] = 3;
```

For an array of structs:

```
vec mystructs[2] = { { 1, 2}, { 2, 3} };
```

initialises the array of structs:

```
mystructs[0].x = 1;
mystructs[0].y = 2;
mystructs[1].x = 2;
mystructs[1].y = 3;
```

To use a `std::vector<vec>` in the manner you expressed add a constructor to the `vec` struct:

```
struct vec
{
    vec(double a_x, double a_y) : x(a_x), y(a_y) {}
    double x,y;
};

std::vector<vec> allPoints;

allPoints.push_back(vec(1,2));
```

Comment: that's very clear.  if I don't add a constructor, I can do `vec temp; temp.x = 1; temp.y=2;` right?

Comment: Yes, then `allPoints.push_back(temp);`.

Comment: Or, `vec temp = {1, 2}; allPoints.push_back(temp);`.

Answer (score 2):

Constructing C-like structs on the fly doesn't work in C++2003. It works in C++2011:

```
std::vector<vec> v;
v.push_back(vec{ 1, 2 });
```

If you need to create a `std::vector<vec>` in C++2003 the best way is probably to create a helper function to initialize your objects

```
vec make_vec(double a, double b) {
    vec v = { a, b };
    return v;
}
...
v.push_back(make_vec(1, 2));
```